# How to run this script without click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

> This question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739366/how-to-pass-this-puzzle-in-javascript); but, there are **some differences**.

---

My friend has an online webpage, which it has an **inline script tag**, there is a JavaScript function:

(#1):

```
var domain = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/';

$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 5;
    countdown = setInterval(function() {
        if (count == 0) {
            $('#countdow').hide();
            $('#link-news').show()
        } else {
            $('#countdow').text(count);
            count--
        }
    }, 1700);
    $('#link-news').click(function() {
        var urls = $('input[name=linknexttop]').val();
        if (urls == 1) {
            $('input[name=linknexttop]').val(2);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: domain + "click.html",
                data: "code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function(html) {
                    //alert(html);
                    window.location = html;
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

---

After waiting in 5 seconds, it will show:

(#2):

```
 <div id="countdow">Please wait ...</div>
    <a href="javascript:(0)" onClick="return false" id="link-news" style="display:none;"><img src="en_tran.png" border="0" name="imgTag" /></a>
    </div>
```

---

Now, I want to send data to `click.html` (in `#1`), **without** click into image `imgTag` (in `#2`). Is there possible to do it with JavaScript?

---

> **Rule for playing:** "I am allowed to insert my code bellow his original code only; so, I am not allowed to change anything in his code. And, the most important: `code=Sh9QA&token=0982ff3066a3c60dbd3ecf9bcafc801b` is random.".

---

Comment: do you want to call click event on image without clicking on image?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the `$('#link-news').click` function by calling `$('#link-news').click()` after the 5 seconds countdown.

Or you can directly call the ajax call in the click function.

```
    if (count == 0) {
        $('#countdow').hide();
        $('#link-news').show();
        $('#link-news').click(); /* This will trigger the click event without actually clicking on the image */
    } else {
        $('#countdow').text(count);
        count--
    }
```

Comment: HoneyBEE's answer is much better though. `trigger('click');` is much faster according to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666471/jquery-advantages-differences-in-trigger-vs-click

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger click function without clicking on it using trigger function of jquery.

```
$( "#link-news" ).trigger( "click" );
```